# New <T> object based on map of attributes

Tags: java

I need to create new T object based on attribute map then I want to somehow feel this object with `oneResult` values

What I tried so far:

```
while (set.next()) {
                list.add(helper.creteObject(set));
}


 public <T> T creteObject(ResultSet oneResult) throws SQLException {
    Set<String> setOfFields = classFieldName.get(aClass.getSimpleName());

    Map<String, ColumnType> fieldFieldType = classFieldFiledType.get(aClass.getSimpleName()); //Map attribute attributeType

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    T pojo = objectMapper.convertValue(fieldFieldType, new TypeReference<T>() {
    });

    for (Field declaredField : pojo.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        ColumnType columnType = getColumnType(declaredField.getType());

        switch (columnType) {
            case INT:
                int anInt = oneResult.getInt(declaredField.getName());

                break;
            case STRING:
                String string = oneResult.getString(declaredField.getName());

        }
    }
}
```

Now how to set this result to `pojo`object

Comment: What is the connection between `T` and the result set object `oneResult`?

Comment: T fields should be filled with oneResult data.

Comment: Yeah I get that part but how are they connected? How do you know that column 'x' from the result set should be mapped to field 'y' in T?

Comment: I see that's the problem